# Limit concept under Complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Prove that $$ \lim_{z\to i} \dfrac{3z^4-2z^3+8z^2-2z+5}{z-i} = 4+4i $$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The number $i$ is a root of both the denominator and the numerator. Since the numerator is a polynomial with real coefficients, it follows that $-i$ is also a root of the polynomial, which means that you can factor out $z^2+1$ on the numerator, which should be easier than factoring out $z-i$.

Answer (score 1):

The numerator contains $z-i$ as a factor so it will be of the form ($z-i$)$f(z)$ where $f(z)$ is some polynomial in $z$ which you can evaluate at i?

Comment: I'll try factor it

Comment: $ (z-i)(3z^3+3iz^2-2z^2+5z-2zi+5i)$ But still i'm with a problem to apply the limit definition to tis

Comment: Just substitute i instead of z? Or are you supposed to do this from the definition only?

Comment: I have to prove the limit but not to show it. Using that delta and epsilon definition

Comment: I find it very hard to believe that you are supposed to use epsilon delta argument for this sort of question. When you get this sort of question you notice that the term z-i exist in both numerator and denominator and hence you can 'cancel' it for the purpose of limit. Hence the limit of the rational function (z-i)f(x)/(z-i) as x-> i is just f(i) which you have calculated